# How to stop propagation without ruining dropdown menu features

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created an object that visually resembles a card (game card) - a card with an image in the top and some information about the card below consisting of texts and symbols. There can be many cards on the page.

Clicking a card brings the user to a new page. This is done by wrapping all card elements in a div with href. Each card also got a dropdown menu with some options. The initial problem with this is that when the dropdown menu is clicked, the card is clicked as well.

I want to stop the card from being clicked when clicking the dropdown menu. The dropdown menu itself should behave as normal when being clicked.

The href div and dropdown elements are shown below (I use onclick in the href div to prevent nesting anchor tags):

```
<div onclick="window.location.href = 'someurl'" style="cursor: pointer;">
    ...
    <a href="#" id="dd" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        ...
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        ...
    </ul>
    ...
</div
```

I tried to put in event.stopPropagation to stop the card from being clicked:

```
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); $('#dd').toggle();">
```

While this approach stop the card from being clicked, it also ignores some of the dropdown menu's features. For example, clicking anywhere on the screen or selecting an option in the menu doesn't close it any more. The menu stays open until the dropdown button is clicked explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get the dropdown out of the div that redirects you to another page.

```
<div onclick="window.location.href = 'someurl'" style="cursor: pointer;">
    ...
    <a href="#" id="dd" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    ...
    </a>
    ...
</div
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible for me to bring the ul tag out of that div. The dropdown menu should also be able to be used on other web pages without the actual card being present.

Answer (score 0):

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/declanmcd/pen/GQQYVO) shows the functionality you want working. It also uses the `event.stopPropagation()` , not sure if it is the same way that you have already tried.
But the difference here is that this captures the click element and you can add our own code to each click event such as close any open menus/redirect to another page/other action.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/declanmcd/pen/GQQYVO)

You haven't shown the full code that you use so I can't tell if this matches your requirements exactly but you may be able to adapt it to your own needs